# Can't get the text from a node in XML

Tags: xml, excel, vba, soap, xmlhttprequest

This is probably a simple question but using xmlhttp, how do I get the text of the token node in this XML? There has to be a better way than this:

```
XML.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling.Text
```

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetToken2Response xmlns="webservice">
      <GetToken2Result>
        <ResponseStatus>
          <ResponseCd>Fail or Success or Warning</ResponseCd>
          <ResponseMsg>string</ResponseMsg>
          <Version>string</Version>
        </ResponseStatus>
        <Token>string</Token>
        <Expiration>double</Expiration>
        <Valid>boolean</Valid>
      </GetToken2Result>
    </GetToken2Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Dude, you *gotta* check out XPath... This `.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild...` business is unmanageable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved your XML to a file, then ran this procedure and it gave me 'string' as the value for Token.

```
Public Sub ReadToken()
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim strToken As String

    strUrl = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "brettville.xml"

    Set objDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    objDoc.async = False
    objDoc.validateOnParse = True
    objDoc.Load strUrl

    strToken = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("Token").Item(0).Text
    Debug.Print "strToken: '" & strToken & "'"
    Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated to include namespaces.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to deal with the 'xmlns="webservice"' in your actual sample xml...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sXML As String
    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim xNodeResult As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xNodeToken As IXMLDOMNode

    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument40

    sXML = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" & _
                 " xmlns:xsd = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" & _
                 " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
                 "<soap:Body>" & _
                 "<GetToken2Response>" & _
                 "<GetToken2Result>" & _
                 "   <ResponseStatus>" & _
                 "     <ResponseCd>Fail or Success or Warning</ResponseCd>" & _
                 "     <ResponseMsg>string</ResponseMsg>" & _
                 "     <Version>string</Version>" & _
                 "   </ResponseStatus>" & _
                 "   <Token>string</Token>" & _
                 "   <Expiration>double</Expiration>" & _
                 "   <Valid>boolean</Valid>" & _
                "</GetToken2Result>" & _
                "</GetToken2Response>" & _
                "</soap:Body>" & _
                "</soap:Envelope>"


    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
              "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"

    xmlDoc.LoadXML (sXML)
    If xmlDoc.parseError.reason <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "Parse error: " & xmlDoc.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    Set xNodeResult = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode( _
       "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetToken2Response/GetToken2Result")
    Debug.Print xNodeResult.XML

    Set xNodeToken = xNodeResult.SelectSingleNode("Token")

    If Not xNodeToken Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print xNodeToken.nodeTypedValue
    Else
        Debug.Print "???"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using XPath but maybe I'm doing the search string wrong.  At first I tried /GetToken2Response/GetToken2Result/Token and it's returning a blank string.  I know the XML token is not blank because I can still get the token using the FirstChild.NextSibling mess.  What would my XPath selection string look like given my XML in my question?  Thanks!

Comment: Your sample is a bit more complex because of the namespaces (an issue I wasn't aware of before now, since this isn't really in my area of expertise...)   I "sort of" got it to work with the exception of the "webservice" namespace, which seems to break it...  See updated answer.